# Using RegEx to mach the beginning of string if end of string is not

Tags: regex, find

I am trying to match lines in a configuration that start with the word "deny" but do not end with the word "log".  This seems terribly elementary but I can not find my solution in any of the numerous forums I have looked.  My beginners mindset led me to try "^deny.* (?!log$)"  Why wouldn't this work?  My understanding is that it would find any strings that begin with "deny" followed by any character for 0 or more digits where the end of line is something other than log.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure.  I am using Solarwinds Network Configuration Manager to search configs and it supports regular expression when building rules.  I've searched all over their website and can't find out which flavor of regex they support.

Answer (score 2):

When given a line like `deny this log`, your `^deny.*(?!log$)` regex (I'm omitting the space that was in your sample question) is evaluated as follows:

- `^deny` matches "deny".
- `.*` means "match 0 or more of any character", so it can match " this log".
- `^(?!log$)` means "make sure that the next characters aren't 'log' then the end of the line."  In this case, they're not - they're just the end of the line - so the regex matches.

Try this regex instead:

`^deny.*$(?<!log)`

"Match deny at the beginning of the string, then match to the end of the line, then use a zero-width negative look-behind assertion to check that whatever we just matched at the end of the line is not 'log'."

**With all of that said...**

Regexes aren't necessarily the best tool for the job.  In this case, a simple Boolean operator like

```
if (/^deny/ and not /log$/)
```

is probably clearer than a more advanced regex like

```
if (/^deny.*$(?<!log)/)
```

Comment: Solarwinds didn't like the '<' in the lookaround.  Thanks for explaining all of it, I see where my logic was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`(?!log$)` is a *zero-width* negative look-ahead assertion that means don't match if immediately ahead at this point in the string is `log` and the end of the string, but the `.*` in your regex has already greedily consumed all the characters right up to the end of the string so there is no way the `log` could then match.

If your regular expression implementation supports look-behinds you could use a regex such as in Josh Kelley's answer, if you were using javascript you could use

```
/^deny(?:.{0,2}|.*(?!log)...)$/m
```

The `m` flag means multiline mode, which makes `^` and `$` match the start and end of every line rather than just the start and end of the string.

Note that three `.` are positioned after the negative look-ahead so that it has space to match `log` if it is there. Including these three dots meant it was also necessary to add the `.{0,2}` option so that strings with from zero to two characters after `deny` would also match. The `(?:a|b)` means a non-capturing group where *a* or *b* has to match.

Comment: Would there be any other way to have regex find this without using look-behinds?  The Solawinds tool didn't seem to like the '<' character used in it.

Comment: @Nathan Edwards. The regex I give above does not include a lookbehind. Just remove the delimiters `/` and the `m` if its not javascript.